# Record and write processes onto a file using C (linux)

Tags: c, linux, fork, writetofile

Can someone help me with this small problem please? I am trying to create a fork bomb and record how many processes a computer creates before something weird happens, but I can't figure out how to write the processes into a text file. I looked around the internet and couldn't find a solution for my problem and I tried doing different things but that didn't work with me also. If you guys can help me out on this matter that would be awesome! Here's my code so far (far from perfect, I know.. D: ).

```
    while(1)
    {
        fork(); // Fork bomb
        write(fd, '\n', sizeof(buf));
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hold on a minute, you want to *read* from a *write only* file? That will not work very well.

Comment: I want to write to file not read. I guess I messed up on that while loop, I'll change it..

Comment: There's that, plus not using the return value of fork, plus not incrementing a counter to record the number of forks made.  Given the goal, there's no point in closing the file.  Probably reading the manual page for fork() should be the advice given in an answer.

Comment: Hmm, could you clarify to me about the return value of fork please? I'll change it again, please check out the new edit..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a file for write+append.

Each forked process will inherit the file descriptor.

In each forked child process, write a single null byte to the file descriptor.

When everything crashes, the size of the file, in bytes, will tell you how many processes were started.

Comment: Thanks for you help, so does it have to be a null byte? or is it possible to actually write the number of child process created in the file using a counter? And also by single null byte you mean `'\n'`?

Comment: Feel free to use any byte that you want. It is not what you write, it is the fact that the size of the file tells you how many processes were started. It looks to me like you're so fixated on writing some number into the file, that you're failing to see a much easier, simpler, way to figure out how many processes were started, using the file's size. In which case each time a new process got started, you can even use a random number generator to pick a number between 0 and 255, and append that byte, a single byte to the file. It's not what you write, it's the file's size, that matters.

Answer (score 1):

### Another idea that would write the number of processes, instead of writing that many bytes

This is a bit complex. I'm writing this answer just for the sake of completeness(and fun!).

Use a process as the "master process". (The easiest way is using the starting process.) Each time a new process is created, a signal(you can use SIGUSR1) would be sent to the master process, so the master process can increment its process counter. (note that incrementing the counter in **every** process wouldn't work because their memory are not shared.) Once fork() has failed, another signal is sent to the master. Once all children have failed(a child would signal the failure only once and the master would have a failure counter in addition to the process counter), the master will write the process counter to the file, and kill all processes in its process group(kill() can kill not only a single process but also a process group).

Cautions:

- You may need to use nice() to avoid the children from preventing the master to execute.
- In order to prevent the children from forking again before all children are killed, you may need to suspend the children before terminating them.